# Nuxt + Vuex: getter doesn't see state variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

Help me, please.
My getters in Vuex don't see the state.
here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-moon-35fiz?file=/store/user.js

user.js:

```
export const state = () => ({
  user: {
    isUserAuthenticated: false,
    user_id: null,
  }
})
export const getters = {
  getUserAuthStatus: (state: any) => {
    console.log('state', state) // it's null, why?
    return state
  }
}
```

calling my getter at the component:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      isUserAuthenticated: 'user/getUserAuthStatus2',
    }),
  },
...
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State name(user) in the index.js file(/store/index.js) and the name of another file(user.js) coincided.
If you change the name of anyone from them - Everything will work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but a different solution.

The plugin `vuex-multi-tab-state` was overwriting my actual state with an old one on init.

Leaving this here for the next to find.